# Why is the nearby cycle of a family of elliptic curves the derived pushforward?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, sheaf-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories

Consider a family of elliptic curves over the open disc $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$, which degenerate to the nodal elliptic curve over $0$, and let $f$ be the map to $D$.  I'm interested in the sheaf on the central fibre which is the derived pushforward of the constant sheaf on one of the generic fibres, i.e. $Rr_*\mathbb{Q}_{f^{-1}(\epsilon)}$, where $r$ is the quotient map $f^{-1}(\epsilon)\to f^{-1}(0)$.

My question is about why I should expect $Rr_*\mathbb{Q}_{f^{-1}(\epsilon)} = \Psi_f\mathbb{Q}_{f^{-1}(0)}$, where $\Psi_f$ is the nearby cycle functor.  Certainly this seems like a nice candidate for the nearby cycle, and in the notes of de Cataldo and Migliorini (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0349.pdf) they state such a property for proper maps $f$ on page 92, in Remark 5.5.1 of the Appendix.   They point to section II.6.13 in "Stratified Morse Theory" by Goresky and MacPherson for details, but I am unable to interpret these results in the appropriate way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Topologically, the nearby cycle functor can be thought as a sheaf of Milnor fibers, i.e., the stalk of cohomology of nearby cycle is isomorphic to the cohomology on the Milnor fiber $F_{f,x}$ at $x$: $\mathcal{H}^i(\Phi_f\mathbb Q)_x=H^i(F_{f,x}\ ,\mathbb Q)$. See second half in the page 24 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9908107.pdf).

Comment: Indeed, but this only tells us about the stalks of the cohomology sheaves.  It doesn't seem to me that the relationship with the derived pushforward (when f is proper) follows right away

Comment: If $x$ is an isolated singular point, and $U$ is a contractible neighborhood of $x$, then $r^{-1}(U)$ is the Milnor fiber at x. In other words, $(R^ir_*\mathbb Q)_x=H^i(F_{f,x}\ ,\mathbb Q)=\mathcal{H}^i(\Phi_f\mathbb Q)_x$, the stalk cohomoolgy of two complex are the same.

Comment: @AGlearner This is a good point, but it still isn't enough to give an isomorphism of complexes